How to factorize the ideal (2) in biquadratic number fields?
Consider the biquadratic number field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n}, \sqrt{m})$, for some square-free integers. My question is how to factorize the ideal $(2)$ in the ring $\mathcal{O}_K$.

There is no hope in using only Kummer-Dedekind Theorem, as the above field is not monogenic for most choices of $m$ and $n$.

I was hoping to use relative Kummer-Dedekind Theorem i.e. to consider $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n}, \sqrt{m})$ as a degree 2 extension over lets, say $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$. The problem is one usually cannot find $\theta$ such that $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})}[\theta]$. I tried to do this having integral basis (Marcus, Number Theory, ex. 2.42).


In total $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n}, \sqrt{m})$ seems to be monogenic over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$ in around 1/3 of cases and only if $m,n$ are coprime.
Any comments/help will be appreciated.

It is a local question and over $\mathbb{Q}_2$ you only have finitely many possible extension.
